# I am trying to convert a Lambert conformal GRIB to coordinates in lat/lon using wgrib2 so that a navigation program can read the data

Tags: python, squid

I am trying to convert the wind grib file found [here](https://www.glerl.noaa.gov/emf/glcfs/grib/FCAST/),

to a format that can be read by marine navigation / routing software which expects lat / long not a lambert projection.

I am trying to convert using `wgrib2`, per steps found here, but failing.

Does anyone have input on a method to convert this using another tool, or the proper steps using wgrib2?

Answer (score 1):

The file is in grib version 1.  Convert it to grib version 2 by

```
grb1to2.pl glcfs-wvp.grb

wgrib2 glcfs-wvp.grb.grb2
```

Comment: I am not sure this solves the question above.  Can you post your converted file here please?